# "Passing" a structure in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to display the information of some games in a list box after opening a file and analysing its contents.
I have basically finished my project, but I can't seem to quite get it to work. What I want to do is to have the information for each game change whenever the index of the list box of titles changes.
My problem is that I am trying to use a structure to store an array and some other data in it, but when the next event happens (the index change) the structure becomes empty and I am not sure how I would pass in an (I think its called instance) to my new function or if there is even a better way to do this.
Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/i0Ga3fcD 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you need any more info I will try my best to help you in anyway possible.

My code snippet:

```
Sub populateListboxWithInfo(ByRef strValidGames)  
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0  
        Dim intLengthOfArray As Integer = strValidGames.Length  

        Do While intCount < intLengthOfArray - 1  
            Dim strArraySplit() As String = strValidGames(intCount).Split(New Char() {","c})  
            lstInformation.Items.Add("Rating: " & strArraySplit(2))  
            lstInformation.Items.Add("Quantity: " & strArraySplit(4))  
            lstInformation.Items.Add("Price (per item): " & strArraySplit(5))  
        Loop  
    End Sub    

Function getValidGames(ByRef gameInfo)  
        Dim intLenghtOfArray As Integer  
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0  
        Dim strArrayValidGames() As String  
        Dim intArrayStore As Integer  

        intLenghtOfArray = gameInfo.strGameInfo.Length  
        Do While intCount < intLenghtOfArray - 2  
            Dim strArraySplit() As String =   gameInfo.strGameInfo(intCount).Split(New Char() {","c})  

            If strArraySplit(3) = gameInfo.CharType Then  
                If strArraySplit(1) = gameInfo.strPlatform Then  
                    ReDim Preserve strArrayValidGames(intArrayStore)  
                    strArrayValidGames(intArrayStore) = gameInfo.strGameInfo(intCount)  
                    intArrayStore += 1  
                End If  
            End If  
            intCount += 1  
        Loop  

        Return strArrayValidGames  
    End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a [mcve] in your post - not all your code, just enough to be a complete example of the problem... and not in pastebin, but *in the question.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to be as brief as possible, but im not sure exactly what I should put in. I hope this is enough.

Comment: No, that's not a complete program. Basically, there should be enough code for us to copy, paste, compile and run - but there should be *nothing* in there which isn't needed in order to demonstrate the problem. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Before you do anything else, turn `Option Strict On` and then address all the errors that arise.  Also, stop passing method parameters by reference unless you specifically need to.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how much code I need to give you without giving you all of it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have done that and now basically every line of code has errors in it. I am pretty new to vb so I have no idea what any of the errors mean when I turned it on.

Comment: You should start by specifying a type for everything.  If you don't then you're using late-binding and everything will be assumed to be `Object`.  That's not allowed with `Option Strict On`.  For a start, your method parameters and your function need types.

Comment: Well I haven't learnt that so its not going to help me right now. I am sure its useful and probably the right way to do it, but If I have no clue as to how/ why I should be doing it then I don't really see a reason for it at this stage.

Comment: Option Strict will help prevent runtime errors by telling you at design time where the code could crash.

Comment: I have been writing this code for about 2 days and it hasn't crashed without me being able to fix it until now where I actually do not know the syntax to get it to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your Game entity ought to be a Class - a Structure is more oriented to small things (up to 16 bytes or so, IIRC). There is usually no need to use [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)-style names (of course, if you have, say. a label, textbox and variable concerning the same thing, then a minimal use of Hungarian notation is likely to be useful).

```
Public Class Game
    Property Platform As String
    Property Title As String
    Property Game As String
    Property Price As Decimal
    Property Rating As Char
    Property Type As Char
    Property GameInfo As String()
End Class
```

When you declare a function, you need to declare the types of the parameters and the type it returns so that the compiler can make sure variable types match.

It is usual to use a `For` loop for a simple loop rather than a `While` loop, and it is conventional to use variables like `i`, `j` and `k` for the loop variable.

If you find yourself using `Redim`, then it is time to consider using a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which automatically adjusts its size when you add new items to it.

So, your `GetValidGames` function could look more like:

```
Function GetValidGames(gameInfo As Game) As String()
    Dim validGames As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To gameInfo.GameInfo.Length - 2
        Dim parts() As String = gameInfo.GameInfo(i).Split(",".ToCharArray())

        If parts(3) = gameInfo.Type Then
            If parts(1) = gameInfo.Platform Then
                validGames.Add(gameInfo.GameInfo(i))
            End If
        End If

    Next

    Return validGames.ToArray()

End Function
```

You didn't show the code which is actually giving you a problem; you need something like:

```
Private Sub lstGames_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim gameName As String = lstGames.SelectedItem.ToString()
    ' show appropriate data
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. 
I use the Hungarian notation because we are pretty forced to for my course as it is the "naming convention" that MUST be followed.
Also we haven't learnt about classes in the course because quite frankly the course I am taking is pretty awful, but I have learnt a little about classes and objects in another course which teaches Python.  
  
I have figured out another way of overcoming my issue by using a global variable and some other sub-par code and it will have to do because there is only 2 weeks of the course left and I am done with VB haha.